# remove ctl00$ from server side button inside master page and make it postback

Tags: c#, master-pages, asp.net-4.5

I tried to remove ctl00$ from server side button's name and id by overriding it's NamingContainer like:

```
namespace NoName
{
   public class MatchingNameButton : Button
    {
        public override Control NamingContainer
        {
            get
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then registered that in aspx page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MatchingNameHtmlTextWriter" Namespace="NoName" Assembly="app_code" %>
```

and then button comes like this:

```
<MatchingNameHtmlTextWriter:MatchingNameButton runat="server" Text="btnTest" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
```

and output is this:

```
<input type="submit" name="btnTest" value="btnTest" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('btnTest', '', true, '', '', false, false))" id="btnTest">
```

this way is good for removing control path. but using this will prevent btnTest_Click event!

and it's so bad for me.

my question is: how should i keep button events in this way?

my .net version is 4.5

all helps will be appreciated.

Comment: Change the [ClientIdMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) at the control, page, or application level.

Comment: Why do you need to change the name anyways?

Comment: as you know, ClientIDMode="static" only keeps ID. But i need to keep Both ID and Name. e.g., for Button with ID="btnTest" the output is: name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$btnTest" and id="btnTest". and this is the output that i want for above button control: name="btnTest" and id="btnTest".

Comment: If you need tight control over the generated HTML, then Web Forms is probably not the right framework to use.

Comment: but it works good. and i'm trying to know why it prevents button events? i've found this solution here [link](http://www.gljakal.com/blog/2007/09/12/getting-rid-of-the-naming-container-in-aspnet-20/). this solution is for .net 2.0.